# unable to load home view using AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer in Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc, maven-3, spring-3

i am new to Spring MVC, i have created spring 3.2 project using maven in eclipse. i am implementing AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer class for java based configuration.

i have following plugins and dependencies in pom.xml

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <!--source level should be 1.6 (which is not Maven default) for java EE 
                6 projects, so let's change it -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- When using xml-less approach, you need to disable Maven's warning 
                about missing web.xml -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
      <!--We need servlet API for compiling the classes. Not needed in runtime
-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!--adding spring mvc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>            
        </dependency>       
        <!-- Add Taglib support -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>           
    </dependencies>
```

Initializer class is as......

```
public class Initializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer{

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[]{WebappConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[]{"/"};
    }       
}
```

WebappConfig class is as......

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"com.sandip.controllers"})
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebappConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{


    //add view Resolver, Tell SpingMVC where to find view scripts
        @Bean
        public InternalResourceViewResolver setupViewResolver() {
            InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
            resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
            resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");

            return resolver;
        }
}
```

and finally i have a HomeController as..........

```
@Controller
public class HomeContoller {      

  @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public String home() {
    return "home";
  }  
}
```

when i run this my project with jetty after maven build it display the following output in browser.....

[image]

springZeroXml is my project name there is no errro in console, please help ..........

Comment: What are you asking? What happens when you make a request to `/`?

Comment: i want to home.jsp on app start, when i make request to / it display some message in browser that i have mentioned above please check in last

Comment: Which server are you deploying to?

Comment: i deploying on tomcat 7 using jetty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did lot of googleing and find out i need to override the addViewControllers method of WebMvcConfigurerAdapter class in WebAppConfig. and code is..........

```
@Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("home");
    }
```